# A Security Package Specific Error Occurred from DCOM

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, dcom, plc, opc

I have created VB.NET application using [**OPC Labs QuickOPC Classic 5.12**](http://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc) to get the data form the PLC server([**SoftwareToolBox's Top server**](http://www.softwaretoolbox.com/topserver/) in remote machine). I have configured the `DCOM setup` in the client machine and server machine. The application is working without any errors, but for past 10 days the applications throws the following error frequently.

> A Security Package Specific Error Occurred.

The error is raised by the `COM/DCOM infrastructure`.

What are the possible reasons/ situations to get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below link for the answer.

http://www.opclabs.com/forum/connections-reconnections-com-dcom/1778-a-security-package-specific-error-occurred-from-dcom